# How to work with Swift file in Objective-C?

Tags: ios, swift, exception, bridging-header

I want to use one third party library which is written in Swift but I am working in Objective-C environment. How to do that? Until now what I have done is:

1. Drag and drop the third party library into my project.
2. It is asking for the bridging header I clicked on yes.
3. In Build settings `defines Modules` no to `yes` in both.
4. Product Module Name showing like `$(PRODUCT_NAME:c99extidentifier)`. I have tried with my project name also.

Now I am getting plenty of errors like below:

> pDatePicker.swift:50:9: Consecutive declarations on a line must be separated by ';'

and

> Ambiguous use of 'open'.

I am getting errors around 50 to 60 same as above errors. Where is my mistake? Can anybody help me?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Are you able to see projectName-Swift.h file in your project ?

**Demo Example is available on github.**

https://github.com/hasyapanchasara/UsingSwiftInObjectiveC

If yes then, Hope you have imported #import "projectName-Swift.h" in Objectice C .m file ?

```
#import "projectName-Swift.h"
```

Then only you would be able to access objective c files in swift code.

**Refer**

https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/BuildingCocoaApps/MixandMatch.html

- Check in build setting
- Objective-C Bridging Header
- ProjectName-Bridging-Header.h has perfect location.

if there is problem with that path than bridging will not work properly , that why when you compile `#import "projectName-Swift.h"` is not getting generate.

[Download](https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B7ooURy3zGWKWHZZdUNnM1VheWM/view?usp=sharing)

Download above sample project.

[image]

Comment: no i didn't find "projectName-Swift.h" how to generate that file. I am using 7.3.1 xcode

Comment: Then there must be something wrong with bridging. check in build setting - Objective-C Bridging Header - ProjectName-Bridging-Header.h has perfect location. if there is problem with that path than bridging will not work properly , that why when you compile #import "projectName-Swift.h" is not getting generate.

Comment: But still i am getting same errors and i didn't find "projectName-Swift.h". I just check out the location i think it is currect location only.

Comment: Check my updates answer, just done with demo for you, download it and check proper configurations.

Comment: Thank you so much.

Comment: yah working fine.But working only xcode 8.if i open xcode7.3.1 then again errors  any reasons.

Comment: Though swift files are in Swift2.2. This is just example i have given, now this way you need to manage.

Answer (score 2):

Make sure, that your swift version in settings is the same as this lib uses; if not, try to translate it by yourself, or set Use Legacy Swift Version to YES